# Starting Points for using VB to Script MS Project (2007)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2007

I have a several plan in MS Project (2007) from which I need to extract information into MS Excel in a certain format and with certain filters.  I'm used to writing VB code to interact with MS Excel.  Does anyone have any pointer to documentation of how I can script MS Project please?

My Google skills are failing me in finding the correct search sting to find any useful information!

Thanks,

Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by recording a macro in MS Project of exporting the information to Excel.

Comment: As ever the simple suggestions are always the best!